# add images to carousel view in xamarin forms 4.4.0

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I have this code for creating a carouselview

```
    <CarouselView x:Name="TheCarousel">
        <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Hey...</x:String>
                <x:String>Psssst...!</x:String>
                <x:String>Did you check out...</x:String>
                <x:String>The awesome new CarouselView</x:String>
                <x:String>In Xamarin.Forms 4.4?!</x:String>
                <x:String> </x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Title" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>`
```

how can i use to view images instead of string ,
im using xamarin 4.3.0 on visual studio 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an `Image` instead of a `Label` in your template

```
<CarouselView x:Name="TheCarousel">
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>[image url goes here]</x:String>
            <x:String>[image url goes here]</x:String>
            <x:String>[image url goes here]</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Image Source="{Binding .}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>`
```